# Can we enable TeX formatting?

Tags: feature-request, formatting

[This question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/31118/10559) and [its first answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/31119/10559) both seem on-topic for this community, since they're about corpus linguistics (which is definitely linguistics). However, they're significantly harder to read because of the lack of math formatting: to an average linguist, `\sqrt[\alpha]{n}` doesn't immediately scan as "the alpha'th root of n".

Other SE sites (such as Math.SE and CS.SE) have LaTeX-esque math formatting; is that something we can enable here? I don't foresee it being used much, but in the few cases it's needed, it would help a lot.

Comment: Maybe an upvote on the older request helps. However, unfortunately it looks like there is not enough support in the community to show [that the site actually needs it](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/510/13238). 13 votes in 6 years is not particularly much.