# Can IPA formatting be enabled on sort-of-beta sites?

Tags: feature-request

I've seen that some StackExchange sites have special formatting for IPA transcriptions: for example, look at [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84222) on Japanese.SE, and what happens to the text between slashes. This seems like a much cleaner solution than e.g. putting IPA in code formatting (which I do to make screen readers separate out the characters, and it also distinguishes transcriptions clearly from the surrounding text), [and it could have other benefits too](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/600/10559).

Is that something that's possible for sort-of-beta sites? [There's been discussion of enabling TeX if it gets enough support](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/510/10559), and I imagine there's quite a lot more use of IPA than of TeX here.

Comment: (Or more generally "phonemic transcription formatting" but that's a mouthful and most phonemic transcription is IPA.)