# Change request for linguistics.stackexchange CSS font-family list

Tags: bug, design

Recently [I raised a question](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/600/1616) on meta.linguistics.stackexchange about which fonts are used to render text formatted as `code`. Briefly: linguists often need to add diacritics to distinguish speech sounds, and diacritics don't align properly in some typefaces (the question has a couple screenshots if you're curious).

Liberation Mono was the culprit in my case, whereas DejaVu Sans Mono does better, but is lower in the CSS `font-family` list for the `code` class. Could we reverse the order of those two typefaces in the SE CSS? I haven't done a thorough testing of the other typefaces higher in the list to see how well they handle diacritics, but if that's a condition for getting this changed I'm willing to do so (at least for the ones that are free).

Comment: This should've been asked on Meta *Stack Exchange*, not Meta *Stack Overflow*.

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing; posting it on meta.stackoverflow was an accident. Regardless, they have migrated it to meta.linguistics.stackexchange, because apparently they think it's a community-specific issue, not a network-wide issue. Presumably because the CSS is allowed to differ at a community level. What I don't know is how to get it implemented.

Comment: I don't think each site does get its own CSS in this way, but I know Beta sites definitely don't. One of our mods will be able to migrate it to MSE. :)

Comment: I think you're wrong about that.  math.stackexchange defaults to a serif typeface, for example. That almost surely reflects a difference in their CSS.

Comment: sorry, I mis-read your previous comment.  I forgot that Linguistics is still in beta.  In that case we probably would need attention from meta.stackexchange to make anything happen.

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt this is a network-wide issue, since it only affects IPA and since we're still in beta, there is very little chance for someone to edit the CSS.

Comment: Each site actually can have various kinds of customizations. Site users and even mods have no access to it of course but the devs and figuring out what we need in Meta is the main step toward getting the devs to make such a change to a given site. But I also forgot that linguistics.SE is still in beta so I'm no sure (-: